# WPF DataBinding Issues - Possible Noob Problems

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, binding

I am trying to bind a ViewModel property of type Visibility to the visibility property on a Dock Panel:

***Updated ViewModel Code***:

```
public class SelectWaferButtonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isClicked;

    public SelectWaferButtonViewModel()
    {
        isClicked = false;
    }

    public bool IsControlVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return isClicked;
        }
        set
        {
            isClicked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsControlVisible");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnButtonClick()
    {
        if (isClicked)
        {
            IsControlVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            IsControlVisible = true;
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

***and here is my updated XAML code***:

```
            <DockPanel
                Name="tvwDockPanel"
                Width="200"
                Visibility="{Binding IsControlVisible, FallbackValue=Collapsed, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"
                DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                <DockPanel
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                    Height="22">
                </DockPanel>
```

and I set the data context in the code behind with this line:

```
    tvwDockPanel.DataContext = btnSelectWaferViewModel;
```

where btnSelectWaferViewModel is the ViewModel object for this situation.

***and for fun, here is my code behind***:

```
public partial class WaferTrackerWindow : Window
{
    List<ISubscribeEvents> subscriptionList;
    SelectWaferButtonViewModel btnSelectWaferViewModel;

    public WaferTrackerWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.InstantiateObjects();
        this.SubscribeEvents();
        this.SetDataContexts();
    }

    #region Methods

    private void SetDataContexts()
    {
        tvwDockPanel.DataContext = btnSelectWaferViewModel.IsControlVisible;
    }
    private void SubscribeEvents()
    {
        foreach (ISubscribeEvents subscriber in subscriptionList)
        {
            subscriber.SubscribeEvents();
        }
    }
    private void InstantiateObjects()
    {
        btnSelectWaferViewModel = new SelectWaferButtonViewModel();
        subscriptionList = new List<ISubscribeEvents>();
        subscriptionList.Add(
            new Classes.WaferTrackerWindow.SelectWaferButtonView(btnSelectWafer, btnSelectWaferViewModel));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

All I want to do click the button btnSelectWafer and have the tvwDockPanel's visibility property to get to set to Visible via binding.  Then when you click again on btnSelectWafer, tvwDockPanel's visibility property gets set back to Collapsed again.  tvwDockPanel's visibility will only ever be either Collapsed or Visible.

Any help would be awesome, I am rather new to this whole data binding concept.

Comment: Two questions, 1) Have you enabled the binding trace messages in visual studio (tools -> options -> debugging -> Output Window), 2) Does anything happen at all or are there any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: Do you see any binding errors in the output window? Also, can you show where you are creating your view model (btnSelectWaferViewModel)?

Comment: Coding Gorilla:  I just enabled the binding errors in my output window, here are the errors i get:

Comment: System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=Visibility; DataItem=null; target element is 'DockPanel' (Name='tvwDockPanel'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'TreeView' (Name='tvwWaferList'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: @user2040460 The key in that error message is: `DataItem=null`, that means it's not bound to an actual instance of anything.  Is `btnSelectWaferViewModel` an actual instance of your view model class?

Comment: Yes, btnSelectWaferViewModel is an actual instance of the SelectWaferViewModel class.

Comment: Could it be that you instantiate your view model after it tries to bind to it? Make sure to set the data context in the constructor of your page's code-behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues here:

First of all, the intent of MVVM (if you're trying to do this with MVVM) is to **separate logic from presentation**. This means that in no way your ViewModel can have a reference to `System.Windows.Controls.Button`, nor to `System.Windows.Visibility`, nor to any other classes inside the `System.Windows` Namespace.

It is not clear to me what your `SelectWaferButtonViewModel` class is doing with the Button, but you need to remove the Button from there.

Also, If you need to manipulate the Visibility of a control from the ViewModel layer, you'd better use a `Boolean` property and the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` in XAML:

ViewModel:

```
public bool IsControlVisible {get;set;} //Don't forget INotifyPropertyChanged!!
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel Visibility="{Binding IsControlVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: I agree with the reference to `Button`, but not necessarily `Visibility`.  I can see the argument, but practically speaking it's silly to go through the hoops of using a converter just to convert from one data type to another.  Either way, this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @CodingGorilla sorry for my bad english, what do you mean by hoops?

Comment: By hoops, I just mean overhead, extra processing needed, etc.  If you can bind directly to a property of type `Visibility` without the need to execute the code involved in a converter, why not just do that?

Comment: @CodingGorilla yeh, I guess one can relax the MVVM "restrictions" a little bit, after all it's just an enum. It all depends on the level of purism in the project, I guess.

Comment: Agreed, like I said I can see the argument, but to me it comes down to testability.  That's the key point in MVVM, constructing a `Button` can inhibit testability, `Visibility` won't.

Comment: This is not an answer to his question, while you have valid points, he was not asking about how to set up his view model properties.

Comment: alright, I used some advice I received here and now I am getting this output:     System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=IsControlVisible; DataItem='Boolean' (HashCode=0); target element is 'DockPanel' (Name='tvwDockPanel'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

Comment: @user2040460 Edit your question with your new code and XAML so we can see it better.

Comment: MVVM has some serious shortcomings in non-trivial implementations. It is generally a great architecture, but you start stumbling over issues like control visibility. Some have begun calling for a new architecture: Model-View-Presenter-ViewModel See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580734.aspx

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I haven't read the full article, but it looks a lot like the mini-framework I built for myself, in which basically there's a third class (I named it Controller), which knows the View AND the ViewModel and glues them together, and can manipulate both directly when needed

Comment: So with the updates I recently posted, here are the new output windows results:

Comment: System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'TreeView' (Name='tvwWaferList'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: System.Windows.Data Warning: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsControlVisible' property not found on 'object' ''Boolean' (HashCode=0)'. BindingExpression:Path=IsControlVisible; DataItem='Boolean' (HashCode=0); target element is 'DockPanel' (Name='tvwDockPanel'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

Comment: System.Windows.Data Information: 19 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=IsControlVisible; DataItem='Boolean' (HashCode=0); target element is 'DockPanel' (Name='tvwDockPanel'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

Comment: System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=IsControlVisible; DataItem='Boolean' (HashCode=0); target element is 'DockPanel' (Name='tvwDockPanel'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

Comment: Your problem is `tvwDockPanel.DataContext = btnSelectWaferViewModel.IsControlVisible;`. You're assigning the DataContext property (which all bindings will be resolved against) to a bool. It should be `tvwDockPanel.DataContext = btnSelectWaferViewModel;`

Comment: HighCore: Thanks a lot man, you have solved my problem.  Please mark this thread as "Answered"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're binding your `DockPanel` to the boolean property of your view model, and then setting the `Visiblity` property of your UI element to the `IsControlVisible` property of the datacontext (which doesn't exist).

Change to:

```
private void SetDataContexts()
{
    tvwDockPanel.DataContext = btnSelectWaferViewModel;
}
```