# MVVM Binding Issue - Another Noob-ish Issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

So here I am again, asking a [very similar question to yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692486/wpf-databinding-issues-possible-noob-problems).  I re-factored my project in order to better follow the MVVM pattern.  Now my binding is no longer working as it was yesterday.  I am trying to bind the visibility of a dock panel to a button.  Here is some of my code:

ViewModel:

```
public class SelectWaferButtonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isClicked;

    public SelectWaferButtonViewModel()
    {
        isClicked = false;
    }

    public bool IsControlVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return isClicked;
        }
        set
        {
            isClicked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsControlVisible");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnButtonClick()
    {
        if (isClicked)
        {
            IsControlVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            IsControlVisible = true;
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
     <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter"/>
     <local:SelectWaferButtonViewModel x:Key="SelectWaferButton" />
     <local:WaferTrackerWindowViewModel x:Key="WindowViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel
     Name="tvwDockPanel"
     DataContext="{StaticResource SelectWaferButton}"
     Width="225"
     Visibility="{Binding IsControlVisible, Mode=TwoWay, 
                  FallbackValue=Collapsed, 
                  Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"
     DockPanel.Dock="Left">
 </DockPanel>
```

My `BoolToVisConverter`:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public BoolToVisibilityConverter() { }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool bValue = (bool) value;
        if (bValue)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility visibility = (Visibility) value;
        if (visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I apologize for a question that is similar to yesterday, but I am struggling with this MVVM stuff since I am quite new to WPF.  Any help will be much appreciated.

- Thanks in advanced,

***EDIT:***
***Here is some extra code snippets for further reference:***

```
public class WaferTrackerWindowViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SelectWaferButtonViewModel btnSelectWaferViewModel;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private DelegateCommand exitCommand;
    private DelegateCommand expandPanelCommand;
    private DelegateCommand selectWaferCommand;

    public WaferTrackerWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.InstantiateObjects();
        initThread.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public string SelectedWafer
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedWafer;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedWafer = value;
        }
    }
    public ICommand ExitCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (exitCommand == null)
            {
                exitCommand = new DelegateCommand(Exit);
            }
            return exitCommand;
        }
    }
    public ICommand ExpandPanelCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (expandPanelCommand == null)
            {
                expandPanelCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExpandPanel);
            }
            return expandPanelCommand;
        }
    }
    public ICommand SelectWaferCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (selectWaferCommand == null)
            {
                selectWaferCommand = new DelegateCommand(SelectWafer);
            }
            return selectWaferCommand;
        }
    }

    private void InstantiateObjects()
    {
        btnSelectWaferViewModel = new SelectWaferButtonViewModel();
        initThread = new BackgroundWorker();
    }
    private void ExpandPanel()
    {
        btnSelectWaferViewModel.OnButtonClick();
    }
    private void SelectWafer()
    {
       //Does Nothing Yet
    }
    private void Exit()
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private void InitThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewPresenter tvwPresenter = new TreeViewPresenter();
        tvwPresenter.WaferList = DataLibrary.GetWaferList();
    }
    private void InitThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        tvwPresenter.TreeView.DataContext = tvwPresenter.ProcessesAndWafers;
        tvwPresenter.WaferListCache = tvwPresenter.ProcessesAndWafers;
        tvwPresenter.ProcessArray = tvwPresenter.WaferListCache.ToArray();
    }
}
```

***When the "expand panel" button gets clicked, it calls the `ExpandPanel` command, which routes the execution to the method "private void ExpandPanel()" in this same class.  Then, in the `ExpandPanel()` method, it calls the `OnButtonClick()` method on the `btnSelectWaferViewModel` object, which will change the `IsControlVisible` property.  This change should then be reflected onto the bound dock panel, but this is not happening***

Kyle

Comment: You know that there already exists a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) in WPF?

Comment: Since he defines the property himself, he could just make it a Visibility, rather than storing it as a Boolean.

Comment: @sircodesalot: Putting `Visbility` into your ViewModel is mixing in too much View logic in my opinion. An `IsVisible` property I think better captures the intent. It's also the opinion of the answer the OP accepted yesterday, so you are really confusing the issue by suggesting they change it back!

Comment: You can simplify your click handler to just `IsControlVisible = !isClicked` rather than the `if/else` block.

Comment: Please show the code relating to how `OnButtonClick` gets called.

Comment: Comment to the Boolean vs Visibility type, my opinion is that you keep the Boolean property if you use the property for more stuff, like enabling/disabling controls or changing other stuff in the view. The Boolean is easier that way.
If you use it only for the StackPanek visibility, agree that you should change it to the Visibility type.

Comment: You might consider using the built-in BooleanToVisibilityConverter from System.Windows.Controls

Comment: Where do you marry the DataContext with the ViewModel? Maybe I just did not see it.

Comment: So how does this `WaferTrackerWindowViewModel` relate to your view (i.e. the actual window with the XAML)? Either way, you are clearly creating a new instance of `SelectWaferButtonViewModel` which is different to the one you are creating with your XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you do this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SelectWaferButtonViewModel x:Key="SelectWaferButton" />
</Window.Resources>
```

WPF will create a new instance of the `SelectWaferButtonViewModel` and add it to it's resources. You then bind to this by setting the `DataContext` using the `StaticResource` with the key.

However, if you are then creating another `SelectWaferButtonViewModel` in your code behind and linking up your command to that instance, then it's not the same instance, so changes to the properties of this unbound instance won't effect your UI. There are a couple of ways around it. You can either a) create a single `SelectWaferButtonViewModel` in the code behind as a property and then bind to that in XAML, or b) Declare your `SelectWaferButtonViewModel` in XAML as you currently have it and then retrieve that instance in your code behind, like this:

```
SelectWaferButtonViewModel swbvm = (SelectWaferButtonViewModel)this.FindResource("SelectWaferButton");
```

**Edit**: So after seeing your last edit, if you want to go with a) then I would suggest you expose `btnSelectWaferViewModel` as a property in your `WaferTrackerWindowViewModel` and then bind to that property with the DataContext of your Window set to the `WaferTrackerWindowViewModel` instance. So you end up with something like:

```
<DockPanel
    Name="tvwDockPanel"
    Width="225"
    Visibility="{Binding MyButton.IsControlVisible, 
        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"
    DockPanel.Dock="Left">
</DockPanel>
```

and:

```
public class WaferTrackerWindowViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SelectWaferButtonViewModel btnSelectWaferViewModel;
    public SelectWaferButtonViewModel MyButton 
    {
        get { return btnSelectWaferViewModel; }
        set
        {
            btnSelectWaferViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyButton");
        }
    }
    //......
```

Comment: I tried this and what I am finding is when this method gets called:        private void ExpandPanel()
        {
            btnSelectWaferViewModel.OnButtonClick();
        }    btnSelecteWaferViewModel object is null, which is odd.  The problem is, after initialization, when the command fires, it uses a different object of the WaferTrackerWindowViewModel than the datacontext was set to in the code behind.  I have no idea why this is, but I break after the command fires and I see everything in the WaferTrackerWindowViewModel class is set to null

Answer (score 2):

(1) ViewModel should be in the `Window.DataContext` section, not the `Window.Resources` section.

(2) In your view model, make your `IsControlVisible` property a `System.Windows.Visibility`, rather than a Boolean, then you don't need a converter.

(3) I don't see any way for `OnButtonClick` to fire, and it really needs to be set up with `ICommand` interface.

(4) You don't need to implement `ConvertBack` because the `Visibility` property you're binding to is one way by definition. There is no way for the user to *set* the `visibility` to `false`.

(5) Don't mix accessing `IsClicked` and it's accessor `IsControlVisible`. Always use the Accessor in MVVM, because you run the risk of accidentally setting `IsClicked` which won't activate `OnPropertyChanged`.

All in all, you're pretty close. Make sure to keep an eye on your "Output" window, it will tell you if a binding is failing for some reason. But yeah, hang in there!

Comment: 1.) I am not using the WindowViewModel to bind this control, I am using a specific ViewModel for this button.  From my experience, I can only set one datacontext in the Window.DataContext property.

Comment: 2.) Using a boolean type and a bool-to-vis converter worked for me yesterday, so i dont think this is the problem

Comment: Comment is irrelevant. Cancelling.

Comment: 3.) OnButtonClick fires due to an ICommand interface that I define.  I did not post this part because I know this ICommand interface does route the button click to this method.  This method then changes the value of the "IsControlVisible" property on the ViewModel.  I can see all of this happen when i step through the code.  For some reason, when the IsControlVisible property changes, the Visibility property of the dock panel does not change, so I believe the issue is in the binding

Comment: 4.) I will take out the ConvertBack method since it is useless in this context

Comment: A couple other things you might try then. (1) Check the output window, it will often tell you if a binding fails. Or (2) you can use a Debug.Writeline in the converter, since (assuming the property is binding) you can find out what's being passed to the converter.

Comment: @kformeck: You say that the OnButtonClick fires, but are you sure it's firing on the same *instance* of your ViewModel? Where's your code that sets up that bit?

Comment: @sircodesalot:  I put the Debug.WriteLine command in my converter and see that is passing the default value, (in this case is "false") to the converter.  However, after the application loads and I click the button, nothing happens.  I don't even see anything else being sent to the converter.  It seems like the binding breaks after initialization.

Comment: Sounds like Matt might be onto something. It seems unlikely that the binding is just breaking (unless you are replacing it somewhere). That does sound like something wrong with the button.

Comment: You normally need the ConvertBack if you are using Mode=TwoWay. But since Visibility is a OneWay property on the DockPanel, the Mode=TwoWay is not necessary. Change it to Mode=OneWay in the binding.

Comment: @MattBurland:  I am in doubt that the OnButtonClick method fires on the same instance of the ViewModel that is bound to the panel.  Here is why:  I am setting up the binding in XAML, setting the DataContext to be the class "SelectWaferButtonViewModel".  After InitializeComponent() gets called, it then calls the "WaferTrackerWindowViewModel" constructor.  This constructor then creates the very first "SelectWaferButtonViewModel" object called "btnSelectWaferViewModel".  I believe I have to bind to this object, not the class, but I have no idea how to do that in XAML

Comment: @all:  I have added another class to my original post that shows how the OnButtonClick() method gets raised when the appropriate button is clicked.